# DataTaskPublisher Generator: What would be the correct function return type?

Tags: ios, combine

**Goal:** I want to make a **dataTaskPublisher** generator that any subscriber can access.

I would like to a create function that *returns a publisher* for use by a general-purpose subscriber.   Something like:

```
let remoteDataPublisher = generatedPublisher(url: <http://....>)
```

Here's what I envision for the function:

```
struct model: Codable {
}
    
func generalPublisher(url: URL) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher  {
        let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                        .map(\.data)
                        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                        .decode(type: model.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

         return remoteDataPublisher

    }
```

Here's the subscriber:

```
remoteDataPublisher
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        switch completion {
                        case .finished:
                            print("Publisher Finished")
                        case let .failure(anError):
                            Swift.print("\n(GovernmentCountryDataList: \(country) Received error: #function", anError)
                        }
                    }, receiveValue: { someValue in
                        SingletonData.shared.governmentCountryDataList = someValue
                        print("GovernmentCountryDataList: \(country)")
                        print(SingletonData.shared.governmentCountryDataList ?? "No Data for \(country)")
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "noteName"), object: DataModelType.GovernmentCountryDataList(country: country))
                    }).store(in: &cancellables)
```

Here's the compiler error:

[image]

**Question:** What's the function's correct return-value Syntax/Data Type? 
 Remedy?

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the `DataTaskPublisher` to a publisher of your `Model` type, so I would suggest change the return type accordingly (and `eraseToAnyPublisher` here):

```
struct Model: Codable { ... }

func generalPublisher(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Model, Error> {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: Model.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

FWIW, I'd suggest starting your type names with uppercase letter, as a matter of convention.

---

Then you can do things like:

```
generalPublisher(for: url)
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("Publisher Finished")

        case let .failure(error):
            print("\n(GovernmentCountryDataList: \(country) Received error: #function", error)
        }
    } receiveValue: { value in
        SingletonData.shared.governmentCountryDataList = value
        print("GovernmentCountryDataList: \(country)")
        print(SingletonData.shared.governmentCountryDataList ?? "No Data for \(country)")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "noteName"), object: DataModelType.GovernmentCountryDataList(country: country))
    }.store(in: &cancellables)
```